# How to get clicked FaceBook button in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a webpage with multiple facebook like buttons. I would like to know which button the user clicked in this JQuery function from FaceBook:

```
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function (response) {

       //$(this) doesn't seem to work...

    });
```

My Facebook button code:

> (function (d, s, id) {
>       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
>       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
>       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
>       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=745992962098989&version=v2.0";
>       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

```
<div class="fb-like"  style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;" data-href="http://10.134.216.25:8009/Vraag?vraagId=@item.vraagID" data-layout="button" data-id="@item.vraagID" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```

I need to be able to read the data-id from that div that contains the button

Comment: You won’t get that info – but the _URL_ that was liked should be passed to your callback function, so if your like buttons point to a different URL each, that could be your solution.

Comment: Yes, the URL differs per like button, how should I extract the URL in the callback function?

Comment: Just log the `response` object to console and see what it contains …

Comment: Thank you, response contains my URL and I can now submit the correct vraagId! :D